# How to install kivy and its dependencies for making android apps on linux ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, python, linux, kivy

I have ubuntu 12.04 and python 2.7, I want to make android apps with kivy. How do I install kivy and all its dependencies and stuff for making android apps?

If you're gonna say read kivy's documentation, I did, its just too confusing I just want someone to explain it to me.

Comment: You should ask the same question in http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Or simply read kivy's [documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html).

Comment: Kivy's documentation confuses me, I just want someone to explain it to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run kivy_novenv.sh and then buildozer_only.sh from here https://github.com/brousch/kivy-installer/tree/master/ubuntu/1204/python27

For an explanation, read the scripts before you run them.